# Trouble accessing certain methods from within Action Mailer in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Thanks for reading this post guys. Rails newbie here with what I'm pretty sure is a fundamental error.

I have a users table with a column 'added_by' that shows which user added them to the database.

[image: User table]

So in this example, Melissa (id:2) was added by Thomas (id:1).

This is my Actionmailer notification_mail.rb, that fires emails when tickets are created:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

add_template_helper HtmlTextHelper

def new_ticket(ticket, user)
    unless user.locale.blank?
      @locale = user.locale
    else
      @locale = Rails.configuration.i18n.default_locale
    end
    title = I18n::translate(:new_ticket, locale: @locale) + ': ' + ticket.subject.to_s

add_attachments(ticket)

unless ticket.message_id.blank?
  headers['Message-ID'] = "<#{ticket.message_id}>"
end

@ticket = ticket
@user = user
assoc = User.find_by_id(user.added_by)
mail(to: user.email, subject: title, from: ticket.reply_from_address) #sends email to ticket creator
mail(to: assoc.email, subject: title, from: ticket.reply_from_address) #sends email to user who added ticket creator

end
```

It should send an email to:

1. The ticket creator.
2. The user who added the ticket creator.

But this is the error I get:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Which comes from this line:

```
mail(to: assoc.email, subject: title, from: ticket.reply_from_address)
```

I'm pretty sure it's to do with me not including something in this file, but I simply can't figure it out despite reading other questions and ruby documentation.

Can someone help?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Ev_, try my answer and it should solve your problem. Let me know if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `added_by` is not present for an user in the database (which is the case for `Thomas` in your given example) then `assoc = User.find_by_id(user.added_by)` won't find the assoc user record and `assoc` will be `nil`. So, if you call `assoc.email` it will fail with this message:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
assoc.try(:email)
```

Or, you can check first if `assoc` is present, only then you send them email:

```
if assoc && assoc.email
  #sends email to user who added ticket creator
  mail(to: assoc.email, subject: title, from: ticket.reply_from_address) 
end
```

Comment: Hey @kmrakibul thanks for the reply. Let me breakdown the results in the console so it's clearer.

Comment: I believe, if you just use my answer's suggestion, that should fix your current issue. Let me know if not.

Comment: Sorry, double post. Here's the console output:

> user=User.find(2)
=> #<User id: 2, email: "melissa@mail.com", added_by: 1>
> User.find_by_id(user.added_by)
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "thomas@mail.com", added_by: nil>
> User.find_by_id(user.added_by).email
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => "thomas@mail.com"


Works in console, but throws error in the browser. Do you know why?

Comment: See you have: `added_by: nil` which causes `assoc` to be `nil` and then when you call `assoc.email` it fails becausein this case `assoc` is nil. I have pointed out two solutions for this problem in my answer. Please follow that and it should be solved. Just check: `if assoc.present?` then send the email as suggested in my answer. Hope this makes it clear to you.

Comment: Hmm. I've changed user_id:1 to added_by:1, and I get the same error. 

`> user=User.find(2) => #<User id: 2, email: "melissa@mail.com", added_by: 1> > User.find_by_id(user.added_by) User Load (1.8ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]] => #<User id: 1, email: "thomas@mail.com", added_by: nil> > User.find_by_id(user.added_by).email User Load (0.6ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]] => "thomas@mail.com"` If you look at the console output, it seems to work correctly. But it doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: Did you try my answer and still you are getting this error?

Comment: Yes, I tried this:

`if assoc.present?
  #sends email to user who added ticket creator
  mail(to: assoc.email, subject: title, from: ticket.reply_from_address) 
end`

and 

`assoc.try(:email)`

Both solutions seems to check that assoc.present? = nil so it skips the mail, which is consistent as my error.

Comment: Ok, try my updated answer please. Which check for both `assoc` and `assoc.email` if they are not `nil`, then try to send the email. `    if assoc && assoc.email . . . ` Try this and let me know.

Comment: that seems to have solved the problem. The view looks a bit messed up, but that's another problem which I'll post separately. Thanks very much!